# Different prefix path to different hosts with nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to achieve the following with nginx. There is one domain with different paths. Each path should proxy the request to a host on different ports:

```
https://example.com/path1 -> 10.0.0.1:8081
https://example.com/path2 -> 10.0.0.1:8082
https://example.com/path3 -> 10.0.0.1:8083
```

Something like this did not work:

```
location /path1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8081;
}

location /path2 {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8082;
}

location /path3 {
  proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8083;
}
```

Is this scenario possible?

EDIT:

This is the config right now on the nginx server

```
server {
  server_name example.com;

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /some/path/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /some/path/privkey.pem;
  ssl_dhparam /some/path/ssl-dhparams.pem;

  location /path1 {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8081;
  }

  location /path2 {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8082;
  }

  location /path3 {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.1:8083;
  }
}

server {
  if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  server_name example.com;
  return 404;
}
```

With this config the prefix path gets removed while loading the site.

```
https://example.com/path1/some/url -> https://example.com/some/url
```

Comment: This is really basic scenario and of course it's possible. Please provide more details, including what exactly doesn't work and your nginx.conf

Comment: @AlexC I added the config

Comment: please share you requests details